# Kibana without Elastic search

Tags: kibana

As we know Elasticsearch stores, search and analyses data and then shows it on Kibana. But I have my data already stored in PostgreSQL and we have to deal with huge data, so storing it in Elasticsearch for seeing a graph on Kibana is not good. There will be duplication like we have same data in Postgres as well as in Elasticsearch and I have huge data (full traffic from a telecom company) and we want to build a reporting tool.

Kibana has all the features that we want but we don't want this duplication of data. I mean we want to use only Kibana. Is it possible? And what should I do to avoid this problem? What are the possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion. If you have all this data, and it is not in a non-sql, document database, your are going about it the wrong way. Either it's elasticsearch or mongo, you should use that kind of databases.

As far as I know, there is no way of using Kibana to display information from something other than Elasticsearch.

You could check out Grafana http://grafana.org/, it has that and more.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For connecting to SQL databases, [Tableau](http://www.tableau.com/) is one of the best options. As I worked with both Tableau and Kibana, I can tell that Tableau supports almost all operations that are supported by Kibana and also Tableau can generate graphs for complex visualizations like

```
sum(field1)/ sum(field2) over values of field3.
```

which can not be generated by using Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

This is way late, but the way I would tackle this is to write an app that pulls data out of your database and publishes to elasticsearch. Sure there is duplication of data, but you can focus on only that data you care about. You also wouldn't be querying against a production database when displaying charts in kibana, which can add its own complications.